# Defining and using xhook in an Angular App

Tags: angular, typescript, xmlhttprequest

How to use [xhook](https://github.com/jpillora/xhook) to interpret ingress and egress http request in an Angular Hybrid App. Following is the `xhook` definition and usage.

```
declare var xhook: any;

xhook.before((request, callback) => {
});

xhook.after((request, response, callback) => {
});
```

`xhook` dependency is added and installed through `package.json` file

```
"dependencies": {
  ...
  "xhook": "^1.4.9"
  ...
}
```

However `ReferenceError: xhook is not defined` error is thrown when the code gets executed.

Other way to include `xhook` too gave different error, say adding in `index.html` file.

Any other way to include the package successfully available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just import it like this:

```
import xhook from 'xhook';
```